# GPO to block searching result in Windows 10

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, gpo

I would like to block the searching result for certain user in Windows 10 by using GPO.
I have updated the the Administrative template, but i don't found how to block the searching result. The goal is to block the use of "cmd.exe" and some other native tools.

Note : i have a GPO for Windows 7, that work well, but doesn't work for Windows 10.

Picture to illustrate my question :

[image: cmd in search result]

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated GPO setting to prevent use of CMD

```
Path: User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System
Setting: Prevent access to the command prompt
```